# Access Method 'RelatedEntitiesQuery' from Class 'RetrieveResponse' even though it's part of the Class

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to use RelatedEntitiesQuery, Target and ColumnSet below which are a part of Retrieve Request, yet I'm met with the error

> 'RetrieveRequest does not contain a definition for RelatedEntitiesQuery'.

```
 var request = new RetrieveRequest()
            {
                RelatedEntitiesQuery = OppCollection,
                Target = new EntityReference("csp_installationsite", isGuid),
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("Installation Site")
            };
 RetrieveResponse response = (RetrieveResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

I've also tried `request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = OppCollection;` and met with same error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The doc for [RetrieveRequest.RelatedEntitiesQuery Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieverequest.relatedentitiesquery?view=dynamics-general-ce-9#applies-to) says that this applies to Version 9.0. Is it a version issue?

Comment: Server version: 9.2.21013.00146 , shouldn't be an issue right? Or does it need to be an exact match? Don't think it would affect the in editor code either, because the code doesn't know what version I'm on until it runs

Comment: If you had an older version, the property might not have been introduced yet. Then this would be a problem at design/compile time, not at runtime. It would only be a problem at runtime if you were working with `dynamic` (which you are not). At design time the compiler works in the background to provide you these errors. Make sure you have all required references and rebuild. Sometimes even closing and reopening VS helps.

Comment: The version I am using of Dynamics is 9.2... which came after 9.0, so it isn't an older version unfortunately, I've attempted a rebuild and ensured I've referenced correctly and still not working.

Comment: What C# libraries are you using?  Do you have an old version of them?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query, Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment and they're all installed on latest stable version

Comment: What is your target framework?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Still loking for a response, haven't made any progress with this yet